# Improve query performance instead of aggregrate function

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, aggregate-functions

I have query where i want to change the `SALES_DATE` to '`01.01.2017`' for the 1st record for a product. It means i want to get every unique product which is stored in `PRODUCT_ID` and check the first `SALES_DATE` on which the product is loaded and change this `SALES_DATE` to '`01.01.2017`'.

I have used the below query which is working but its hitting the performance it seems. So is there any other i can write the same logic and improves the performance?

```
    UPDATE TEST_GROUP sd
set SALES_DATE = TO_DATE ('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
where SALES_DATE =
 ( select min(SALES_DATE)
   from TEST_GROUP sd2
   where sd.PRODUCT_ID = sd2.PRODUCT_ID   
 )
 and sd.SALES_DATE  <> TO_DATE ('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Comment: `SET` is missing in your update, this is not a valid `UPDATE`

Comment: i have updated now

Comment: Oracle also does not support the `update from` syntax. I therefore highly doubt that your query is working. Please choose the right tags and/or provide us with the correct query + table structure + test data.

Comment: yes typo mistake i have edited now

Comment: that update doesn't look right - did you mean `...set sales_date = to_date('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') where (select min(sales_date)...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a MERGE statement may improve your performance:

```
MERGE INTO test_group tgt
  USING (SELECT product_id,
                ROWID r_id,
                row_number() over (partition by product_id ORDER BY sales_date) rn
         FROM   test_group) src
    ON (tgt.rowid = src.r_id AND src.rn = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET sales_date = to_date('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  WHERE sales_date != to_date('01.01.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Adding an index on (product_id, sales_date) (if it doesn't already exist) should also aid performance on both the merge and your original update statement.

Comment: i am checking just select part to check whether i am getting the same amount of records or not but getting errors as sql command not properly ended.

Comment: There was a missing bracket; I've fixed that now.

Comment: actually there is no index but i have only 15000 records in the table so in this case also will it take too much time ?

Comment: how long is "too much time"? I wouldn't expect 15000 records to take particularly long to be updated... And if you want to see the impact of my answer, why not run it and see what effect it has? Only you can really answer your own question!

Comment: because i ma getting error as not a group by expression in the inner select query

Comment: now i am getting error as from keyword not found where expected but the query looks fine to me

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing comma (although I hope you managed to work that out for yourself...)

Comment: its my mistake sorry. Actually i was able to run your query. But it didnt satisfy the logic. I have updated the correct query in my question. I want to update the sales_date to 01-01-2017 only for the first record of product where sales_date is min. In you query its updated for all such products as sales_date to 01-01-2017. I am trying to modify your query accordingly. Do you know how to do that ? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? My merge statement and your update statement do the same thing, as you can see in [this LiveSql script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ffrpp5pm83wyshgir8xh9vfp7). They both update just the earliest dated row for each product_id. Is that not what you wanted?